# VBA - “Can't find Project or Library” for custom .xla files that are correctly located

Tags: excel, vba

We have a main `.xls` file that references several `.xla` files in the same folder. Most of the time, all the references open fine, but sometimes, seemingly at random, some users will starting getting `Can't find Project or Library.`.

When looking at what is missing, it will be one of the `.xla` files; however, the path to the file it is looking for is exactly correct and the same files will work fine for others. We've found that if we rename the folder containing all the files, the problem generally goes away.

Due to users having shortcuts to the folder, we can't generally rename the folder though. The only way around it we have found is to create another `.xls` file that opens all the `.xla` files in the right order and then opens the main `.xls` file last. That works but it is confusing to users as to which version of the `.xls` file they should use.

Anyone have any ideas what causes Excel to think something is missing when it is exactly where the reference is pointing or how to fix it (other than renaming the folder)?

Comment: You say "some users" so does that mean the xla files are on a network share? Have you gone through Tools > References (VBA Editor Menu) and looked for "MISSING: " references? Also, what does "We have a main .xls file that references several .xla files" mean? Are the xla files added via Tools > Addins?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to open the file before you can access the code in that.